# save audio file to binarydata for a coredata/cloudkit swift

Tags: swift, audio, core-data, cloudkit

I need to save audio file to binarydata for a coredata/cloudkit project and read it back.

For an image I would do:

To save: let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

To load: let image = UIImage(data: data)

Does anyone knows how to do this with audioFile?

Many thanks

Comment: For cloudkit you want to use CKAsset, and data for core data.